# I am looking for a way to remotely teach a class

Tags: software, video-conference

So I am a single individual and do not have access to any university schemes related to my issue.

I would like to be able to use my wacom device (an pen that allows me to write down on the computer) so that I am able to handwrite equations etc to my students.

I also need to be able to conference with more than one student, but typically less than five.

Last but not least while video conferencing I want to be able to handwrite (like in a blackboard) so that all the students will be able to see in real time what I am handwriting on the "blackboard"

If possible (but not necessary in case it excludes solutions you may have in mind) I would like that black board to be interactive so that students can draw on it as well.

Also since I am a single individual the software or service has either to be free or at a "consumer service" price I am not able to spent e.g 300$ a month for such a service.

Comment: There is a selection of online whiteboard services. Have you tried any of them? Do they solve your problem?

Comment: @Dmitry Savostyanov English is not my native language and I struggle to find such a service especially since most of the ones I found are either described very vaguely and require you to post an inquiry or are very expensive obviously aimed at institutions none of the ones I found  mention this "blackboard" functionality they may have it but I couldnt see that feature explicitly stated in the website that's why I tried my luck here :)

Comment: I use https://whiteboardfox.com for collaborative hand-writing.

Comment: Zoom has such a functionality (they call it "whiteboard") and it is not too expensive (14€ per month or 140€ per year).

Answer (score 5):

For the video conferencing software, I recommend [Discord](https://discord.com/).  It was started in the gaming community. When we all went online in March, several of the students in one of my classes suggested it, and I went with it.

It's very good for low-bandwidth voice channels, and also allows screen-sharing.  The only downside is that it only allows 25 people to see the screen share at once.

To get around that, a colleague of mine streams his video feed to Twitch (another gaming site).

As far as drawing, I use Microsoft's OneNote software. Its drawing allows my to use my Wacom tablet to write on top of PDFs that I upload into it.

Below is a still from one of my video lectures, showing my (awful) handwriting on top of a PDF in OneNote. This was streamed to YouTube for recording purposes, but most of the students were watching live.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, this would be my plan B (I thought something similar with OBS and twitch) since it does not allow (at least as far as I understand correct me if I am wrong) for the participants to e.g ask a question while I draw something on screen.
As for the number of the participants it wont be an issue I think since usually I have classes of less than 5

Comment: @papajo Yes, I use Streamlabs OBS to compose the display (the icon in the top left and the mini-me in the bottom right).  That also lets me stream directly to YouTube. The main reason for that, as I said, is for recording purposes. Some students need to miss lectures, and this way they get to review them afterwards.

Comment: Note though that Discord can be very confusing to people who aren't very technical. A great suggestion for a math or CS department, but it might be more challenging with other students

Comment: @AzorAhai--hehim I find Discord less confusing than MS Teams to use, and most institutional users (business) go the Teams route....

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 I've never used Teams, I don't know anyone who does. So I can't speak to that. But among my friends, it's clear the gamer-y and CS types find Discord much easier to use than my non-techy friends.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Peter K and also have used Discord in a teaching situation, but also MS Teams which my institution uses.

I use the video and screen sharing capabilities of these in conjunction with [OpenBoard](https://openboard.ch/download.en.html) which is free and designed for online teaching and should work well with  the tablet.

[image]

Comment: Ooh. I might have to look at OpenBoard.  Thanks for the tip! :-)